# How to write Makefile to package a .so dynamic library that will install all required links

Tags: apt, package-management

I need help in writing a Makefile that installs my library on Linux FHS. https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-sharedlibs.html#s-sharedlibs-dev says that there should be a link from `.so` to `.so.$(version).$(minor)` and a link from `.so.$(version)` to `.so` to `.so.$(version).$(minor)`. Below is snippet from my Makefile

```
install -D ${CND_ARTIFACT_PATH_${CONF}} $(DESTDIR)/usr/lib/${CND_ARTIFACT_NAME_${CONF}}.$(version).0.0
ln -s $(DESTDIR)/usr/lib/${CND_ARTIFACT_NAME_${CONF}}.$(version).0.0 $(DESTDIR)/usr/lib/${CND_ARTIFACT_NAME_${CONF}}
ln -s $(DESTDIR)/usr/lib/${CND_ARTIFACT_NAME_${CONF}}.$(version).0.0 $(DESTDIR)/usr/lib/${CND_ARTIFACT_NAME_${CONF}}.$(version)
```

after packaging with `dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -b` and installing the package the soft links created are pointing to actual .so used to build the package but not to the .so that was installed in `/usr/lib/`

```
gowtham@VBUbu:~$ ls -la /usr/lib/libbase.so.1*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     67 Aug 25 00:35 /usr/lib/libbase.so.1 -> /home/gowtham/Packages/base-1.0/debian/tmp/usr/lib/libbase.so.1.0.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 170588 Aug 25 00:35 /usr/lib/libbase.so.1.0.0
```

Comment: Those links are usually relative and not absolute. I think you'll have to `cd` to the `$(DESTDIR)/usr/lib` directory and do `ln -s ${CND_ARTIFACT_NAME_${CONF}}.$(version).0.0 ${CND_ARTIFACT_NAME_${CONF}}`.

Comment: @muru It worked! I actually tried it before but I couldn't succeed then due to some other mistake. Anyway I retried after your comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the symbolic links to libraries I could find on my system, the links were all relative, and not absolute:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       14 Aug  9 03:52 libwine.so -> libwine.so.1.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       14 Aug  9 03:52 libwine.so.1 -> libwine.so.1.0
```

So, it looks like the Makefile should do a `cd` to the library folder and make relative symbolic links:

```
cd $(DESTDIR)/usr/lib
ln -s ${CND_ARTIFACT_NAME_${CONF}}.$(version).0.0 ${CND_ARTIFACT_NAME_${CONF}}
ln -s ${CND_ARTIFACT_NAME_${CONF}}.$(version).0.0 ${CND_ARTIFACT_NAME_${CONF}}.$(version)
cd -
```